# Javascript Array.reduce weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this small code snippet:

```
let data = [1, 2];
let newBody = {};

let newArray = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  newBody.doc = current;
  acc.push(newBody);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

The result is:

newArray = [ { doc: 2 }, { doc: 2 } ]

If I'm redeclaring the empty newBody inside the iteration, its working fine. 
But if I declare it outside its getting the value of the last array element and applying it to all the other elements and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You're using the **same** object reference over and over, modifying the **one** object, and pushing multiple references to the same object into an array. `If I'm redeclaring the empty newBody inside the iteration, its working fine.` <-- that's the answer.

Comment: Also, this is rather a job for `.map()` as opposed to `.reduce()`. What your code does is equivalent to this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/82ezLu3o/

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yeah, As one of the comment said its because of closures, so I guess I have to look into closures more indepth.

ChrisG - This is a simplified version of what I'm doing inside the reduce so that's why it looks like I should've used .map

Answer (score 1):

You are using a closure on accident. Put the `newBody` in it's proper scope:

```
let data = [1, 2];

let newArray = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  let newBody = {};
  newBody.doc = current;
  acc.push(newBody);
  return acc;
}, []);
```